# Django ORM запрос

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Нужна помощь составить запрос, у меня есть модель:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    item = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=50))
    total = models.IntegerField()
```

Нужно сделать запрос для вывода только первых пяти customer по полю total (это я знаю, как сделать), но далее в поле item каждого customer нужно вывести только те камни, которые встречаются не менее двух раз у других customer этого топ пять.

Как правильно реализовать этот запрос?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Можно выбрать топ-5 `members` по `total`:

```
members_qry = Member.objects.order_by('-total')[:5]
```

и записать в словарь:

```
members = [{'customer': m.customer, 'stones': m.item, 'total': m.total} for m in members_qry]
```

Допустим, `members` выглядит так:

```
>>> members
[
    {'customer': 'joe', 'total': 13, 'stones': ['бриллиант', 'сапфир', 'аметист']},
    {'customer': 'dou', 'total': 12, 'stones': ['изумруд', 'сапфир', 'малахит']},
    {'customer': 'foo', 'total': 12, 'stones': ['топаз', 'берилл', 'оникс', 'аметист', 'изумруд']},
    {'customer': 'bar', 'total': 9, 'stones': ['изумруд', 'сапфир', 'малахит']},
    {'customer': 'spam', 'total': 9, 'stones': ['топаз', 'аметист', 'сапфир', 'берилл']}
]
```

Тогда количество камней у всех будет:

```
stones_dict = dict()

for m in members:
    for s in m['stones']:
        stones_dict[s] = stones_dict.get(s, 0) + 1
```

в `stones_dict`:

```
>>> stones_dict
{'бриллиант': 1, 'сапфир': 4, 'аметист': 3, 'изумруд': 3, 'малахит': 2, 'топаз': 2, 'берилл': 2, 'оникс': 1}
```

И потом удалить те камни, которые встречаются у двух и меньше `members`:

```
for m in members:
    for s in m['stones'].copy():
        if stones_dict[s] < 3:
            m['stones'].remove(s)
```

В итоге в `members`:

```
>>> members
[
    {'customer': 'joe', 'total': 13, 'stones': ['сапфир', 'аметист']}, 
    {'customer': 'dou', 'total': 12, 'stones': ['изумруд', 'сапфир']}, 
    {'customer': 'foo', 'total': 12, 'stones': ['аметист', 'изумруд']}, 
    {'customer': 'bar', 'total': 9, 'stones': ['изумруд', 'сапфир']}, 
    {'customer': 'spam', 'total': 9, 'stones': ['аметист', 'сапфир']}
]
```

Comment: Я еще думал, что можно сделать так. Сделать фильтр топ5, зачем среди этого списка перебирать пользователей, далее перебирать их камни, и вычитать счетчик количества всех камней этого топа из счетчика количества камней выбранного пользователя, если результат больше нуля, то записывать камень в список, если же нет, то продолжить

Comment: @messageman ничего не понял )) "вычитать счетчик количества всех камней этого топа из счетчика количества камней выбранного пользователя" - не вычитать, а удалять из списка те, которые встречаются менее двух раз (так в вопросе)

Comment: у вас item - это ArrayField, как вы скажете запросу не брать содержимое, удовлетворяющее вашим условиям???

Comment: написал так, как вы расписали, но все равно выводит все итемы

Comment: @messageman покажите stones_dict? есть камни, у которых значение меньше 3? если нет, то они "встречаются не менее двух раз у других customer этого топ пять", и, соответственно, у всех в item останется то, что было изначально

Comment: камней со значением меньше 3 нет

Comment: именно ;) потому все списки stones в каждом из словарей members остаются без изменения (не удаляются), т.к. это соответствует условию "встречаются не менее двух раз у других customer этого топ"

Comment: все, понял. Просто в конечном виде, чтоб у пользователя названия камней при выводе не повторялись, это меня и сбивало с толку, что при выводе по-прежнему выводит целый список

Comment: а почему выводит у foo берилл, если больше ни у кого нет такого гема?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119504/discussion-between-jack-os-and-messageman).